# sklearn scoring for regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, scoring

When looking for a model such as linearregresion or DecisionTreeRegressor, which is the best scoring to use? In https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html we can see the following:

explained_variance, max_error, neg_mean_absolute_error, neg_mean_squared_error, mean_squared_error, neg_root_mean_squared_error, neg_mean_squared_log_error, neg_median_absolute_error, r2, neg_mean_poisson_deviance, neg_mean_gamma_deviance, neg_mean_absol

However for someone introducing to the field is not easy to decide which to use. For a simple linear regression I would use r2 (probably because is the one I'm used to from the school), but is the best? However, for a decisionTreeRegressor, is it also good this parameter or is it better to use another one?

Also, the fitting should be good if, in the case of r^2=1 (altough Anscombe's quartet). How about for the rest?

Comment: "which is the best scoring to use?" is entirely down to your use-case. Unfortunately the ony way to understand when to use each metric is to study them in relation to the problem you're trying to solve. It's a bit like asking "What is the best programming language to learn?" The answer is "It depends"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info (applicable also here).

Answer (score 1):

There's no *best* scoring function. The one you pick should depend on your problem and what you're trying to measure.

I suggested you take a look at the [regression metrics section](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) of the page you linked. You can find descriptions and suggestions of usage, for example (for MSLE):

> This metric is best to use when targets having exponential growth, such as population counts, average sales of a commodity over a span of years etc.

So, a good question on this topic would be something like *I am studying X and am trying to measure Y, which scoring metric should I be using?*